# export default function returns undefined value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

ok, so, I want to separate my security related functions in a separate functional component. For this I ended up creating the below functional component

```
import { useAuthDispatch, logout, useAuthState } from "../context/context";

const AppSecurity = () => {
  

  const isAdminUser = () => {
    console.log("+++ isAdminUser called...");
    return true;
  };

  const isSuperUser = () => {
    console.log("+++ isSuperUser called...");
    return true;
  };
};

export default AppSecurity;
```

The grand plan is to implement both isAdminUser and isSuperUser functions eventually to go through security contexts and return true or false based on the logged in user but that's later some time. My current issue is when I import this AppSecurity functional component is other functional component and try to access the **isAdminUser** and **isSuperUser** functions, I get **undefined** values...see below

```
import AppSecurity from '../../utils/security'

function Header() {

  const isAdminUser = AppSecurity.isAdminUser;
  const isSuperUser = AppSecurity.isSuperUser;

  console.log('isAdminUser : ', isAdminUser)
  console.log('isAdminUser : ', isSuperUser)
}

export default Header;
```

in the above code BOTH console log returns '**undefined**' values. I am also noticing that none of the console logging inside those 2 functions within the AppSecurity shows up. I tried to change the way I access those two functions in my Header as per below and getting webpack error that those are not functions ....Any idea?

```
const isAdminUser = AppSecurity.isAdminUser();
const isSuperUser = AppSecurity.isSuperUser();
```

see below webpack error ...

```
TypeError: _utils_security__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17__.default.isAdminUser is not a function
Header
src/components/ui/header.component.jsx:200
  
> 200 | const isAdminUser = AppSecurity.isAdminUser();
      | ^  201 | const isSuperUser = AppSecurity.isSuperUser();
  202 | console.log('isAdminUser : ', isAdminUser)
  203 | const toggleDrawer = () => {
```

Comment: That's not quite how functions work. Defining a function inside another one doesn't mean that that nested function is accessible as some static property of the outer function definition. Either use an object or a class, or do what De C recommended in his answer, return it and call it to get those returned functions

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the `AppSecurity` function. You need to add the following return statement in the `AppSecurity` function.

```
  return { isAdminUser, isSuperUser };
```

you need to export it like, since `AppSecurity` is a function.

```
export default AppSecurity();
```

You need to return an object that contains both `isAdminUser` and `isSuperUser` property in an object

```
const AppSecurity = () => {
  

  const isAdminUser = () => {
    console.log("+++ isAdminUser called...");
    return true;
  };

  const isSuperUser = () => {
    console.log("+++ isSuperUser called...");
    return true;
  };

  return { isAdminUser, isSuperUser };
};

export default AppSecurity();
```

Comment: If they do that, they'd also have to **call** `AppSecurity` when using it (since it's a function), i.e. `const isAdminUser = AppSecurity().isAdminUser;`

Comment: ok, first of thanks very much for all those who have responded. Much appreciated. Now, I followed @De C's path while it worked as expected, it may not fit with my requirements as I need to use context hook and I am getting an error ..see the code below ...

Comment: import { useAuthDispatch, logout, useAuthState } from "../context/context";

const AppSecurity = () => {
    //const userDetails = useAuthState();
  

  const isAdminUser = () => {
    console.log("+++ isAdminUser called...");
    //console.log('+++ userDetails TOKEN..', userDetails.token)
    return true;
  };

  const isSuperUser = () => {
    return true;
  };
  return { isAdminUser, isSuperUser };
};

export default AppSecurity();

Answer (score 0):

You are Exporting a function which in having local functions, try exporting an Object like below

```js
import { useAuthDispatch, logout, useAuthState } from "../context/context";

const AppSecurity = {
  isAdminUser: () => {
    console.log("+++ isAdminUser called...");
    return true;
  },
  isSuperUser: () => {
    console.log("+++ isSuperUser called...");
    return true;
  }
};

export default AppSecurity;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravikumar for the solution though I also need to use Context API within this security.js and I am getting an error if I add const userDetails = useAuthState(); the  useAuthState code is as per below ... export const useAuthState = () => {
 const context = React.useContext(AuthStateContext);
 if (context === undefined) {
  throw new Error('useAuthState must be used within a AuthProvider');
 }
    
 return context;
}

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks everyone who quickly posted various answers. I must admit that I was missing a few basic stuff. After making below changes, now I can call those functions and can also use the useAuthState() hook inside those functions. The issue turned out to be uppercase first letter of the function names..see below... IsAdminUser and IsSuperUser instead of **is**AdminUser and **is**SuperUser  Once again basic mistake on my side.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useAuthDispatch, logout, useAuthState } from "../context";

  export const IsAdminUser = () => {
    const userDetails = useAuthState();
    console.log("+++ IsAdminUser called...");
    return true;
  };

  export const IsSuperUser = () => {
    console.log("+++ IsSuperUser called...");
    return false;
  };
```